# IOS server-based application

Tags: ios

I know that this is not really a code related question, but this is driving me crazy.
I have an IOS app that enables users to coddect to a common "cloud" and share data with each other. Exactly like Facebook or whats' app. The problem is that I don't seem to find a service I can use. I need functions such as upload, download, delete, check for existence, update, etc. and without a limit of requests/space. StackMob with amazon s3 was perfect but now that stackMob is down I have to delete all of my work. What other similar service could I use? Does anyone with experience knows how to do in this cases? How do I know that the next won't close down?

Comment: https://www.parse.com/

Comment: Read this http://www.objc.io/issue-10/data-synchronization.html, it also has a list of currently active projects that you could use such as Parse.

Comment: parse has a really low limit in space (only 20 gb). I heard about buying server space. Would this mean that I have to create my own api for dealing with the data?

Comment: @Alessandro you can get more space with parse, but you have to pay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out parse.com? Depending on your long term plans, you might want to write your own custom backend.

Comment: "Depending on your long term plans, you might want to write your own custom backend". How does this work? Do you need to create your own api and then you can use any available space on a server?

Comment: I would highly recommend looking into Heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart). This would require you to write your own backend and setup a database, but the cost is much lower if you plan to pursue this project and have many users/data.